# Download & concat js file using gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have 3 'cdn' files.

Eg.

```
http://www.cdn.com/js/script1.js (size: 10KB)
http://www.cdn.com/js/script2.js (size: 2KB)
http://www.cdn.com/js/script3.js (size: 15KB)
```

I need to download the above 3 files & concat to 'script.js'.
By running gulp command i had created the 'script.js'.
But the first file(script1.js) is missing in 'script.js'. Other two files are there.

I had changed the order 
i.e.

```
download(
        [
            "http://www.cdn.com/js/script2.js",(size: 2KB)
            "http://www.cdn.com/js/script3.js",(size: 15KB)
            "http://www.cdn.com/js/script1.js",(size: 10KB)
        ])
```

This time script3.js is missing, but script1.js is there.

My 'gulp.js' file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var download = require("gulp-download-stream");
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

var FileSystem = require('fs');
var PackageJSON = JSON.parse(FileSystem.readFileSync('package.json'));
var Destination = "cdn/"+PackageJSON.version;

gulp.task('clean', function() 
{
    return del([Destination]);
});

gulp.task('js', function() 
{
    download(
    [
        "http://www.cdn.com/js/script1.js",
        "http://www.cdn.com/js/script2.js",
        "http://www.cdn.com/js/script3.js",
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("temp/"));
    return gulp.src("temp/*.js")
    .pipe(concat('script.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(Destination+"/"));
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean','js']);
```

'package.json'

```
{
    "name": "",
    "version": "4.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "",
    "dependencies":
    {
        "gulp": "^3.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies":
    {
        "del": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-download-stream":"^0.0.1"
    },
    "scripts":
    {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may have had this originally, but watch your trailing commas in the array:

```
 download(
[
    "http://www.cdn.com/js/script1.js",
    "http://www.cdn.com/js/script2.js",
    "http://www.cdn.com/js/script3.js"
])
```

I removed the last comma.  Perhaps that is mucking up your download call.